# Extracting key Value from Json - Mule Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule-esb, mule4

I'm unable to get the key value from Json. Please find the details below xml to Json conversion.

Input XML:

```
 <DeliveryDetails>
  <Information>
    <InformationLines>
        <InformationLine>
            <InformationLineId>1001</InformationLineId>
            <ProductId>PREBC518</ProductId>
            <ProductDescr>Bag  </ProductDescr>
            <NumberBase>150.00000000</NumberBase>
            <UnitBase>BAG</UnitBase>               
        </InformationLine>
        <InformationLine>
            <InformationLineId>1001</InformationLineId>
            <ProductId>PREBC518</ProductId>
            <ProductDescr>Bag delivery</ProductDescr>
            <NumberBase>150.00</NumberBase>
            <UnitBase>BAG</UnitBase>               
        </InformationLine>
        <InformationLine>
            <InformationLineId>1003</InformationLineId>
            <ProductId>PREBC518</ProductId>
            <ProductDescr>test</ProductDescr>
            <NumberBase>70.00</NumberBase>
            <UnitBase>BAG</UnitBase>               
        </InformationLine>
        <InformationLine>
            <InformationLineId>1005</InformationLineId>
            <ProductId>PREBC518</ProductId>
            <ProductDescr> dress </ProductDescr>
            <NumberBase>80.00</NumberBase>
            <UnitBase>BAG</UnitBase>               
        </InformationLine>               
    </InformationLines>
</Information>
```

```
       %dw 2.0
       output application/json
       var nb =  payload.DeliveryDetails.Information.InformationLines.*InformationLine groupBy 
          ($.InformationLineId  ) mapObject (value,key) -> { 
          (key): sum (value.NumberBase)
           }
       var test = "1001"
       ---
       nb
```

Above expression gives the below result

```
        {

          "1005": "80.00",
          "1003": "70.00",
          "1001": 300.00
        }
```

Having 2 questions

1) when i directly use `ts.'1001'` i can able to get `"300.00"` if i use `"ts.test"` it is not  fetching the value?, ideally in the above `test` can be assigned to different value hence im looking for dynamic retrieval.

2) Using the above XML Input  on condition based  "($.InformationLineId == "1001" ) i only need to get 'sum of BaseNumber'.

I believe it easily achieve by using `reduce` function in Mule4 but not sure how to do condition based in `reduce`. Needn't required to use the above dataweave logic. I just need to get specific value  if 
 `InformationLineId =="1001"` its sum of "BaseNumber"

Please let me know if the question is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your questions:
   1) the answer is [dynamic selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-selectors#dynamic_selector) so for your example you can do `ts."${test}"`
   2) Regarding this question is not clear what you are trying to do next time please post the expected output but what I get is that you are trying to get the sum of all `NumberBase` whom `InformationLineId` is the value of variable `test`. If so then the answer will be

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var test = "1001"

var nb =  sum(payload.DeliveryDetails.Information.InformationLines.*InformationLine 
            filter ($.InformationLineId == test) 
            map ((value) -> value.NumberBase as Number))

---
nb
```

If not please rephrase your question

Comment: Super!! Exactly working. Thanks for the quick answer and response.